# Where can I find latest gradle version in android studio?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I try to build the Project 1, I get the following error. It seems that both gradle-3.0.0-beta6 and gradle-3.0.0-beta9 are unavailable.

Where can I find latest gradle version in android studio? Could you tell me a URL which can list all available gradle versions?

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta6.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/E:/Android_Studio_3.1/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-beta6/gradle-3.0.0-beta6.pom
    file:/E:/Android_Studio_3.1/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-beta6/gradle-3.0.0-beta6.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-beta6/gradle-3.0.0-beta6.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-beta6/gradle-3.0.0-beta6.jar
```

**Project 1**

```
buildscript {
    ext.support_version =  '26.0.0'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'
    ext.anko_version = '0.10.1'


    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:gradle-3.0.0-beta6'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use + sign instead of version no. It will automatically picks the latest one available

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

See here for release/version information of gradle android plugin: https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view

---

But if you want to install a specific version.Check the url below.

https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Here you can found the one you required. FYI beta versions are not available.
[image]

Inside your Android Studio's project tree, open the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties. Change this entry to the one you need:`

> **distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip**

Comment: Thanks! Why is the latest grade version on https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view  2.5.0-alpha-preview-02 , I remember grade version has over 3.0

Comment: Latest stable release is 2.3.3. Others are alpha beta versions

Comment: Thanks, where can I find all version include alpha beta versions? The latest version is only 2.5.0-alpha-preview-02

Comment: There is a link there "View all" under Versions where you can view all of the releases

Comment: Thanks! I have clicked "View all",  the latest version is only 2.5.0-alpha-preview-02

Answer (score 2):

As per official documents : *You should not use dynamic dependencies in version* numbers, such as 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.+'. Using this feature can cause unexpected version updates and difficulty resolving version differences.

If the specified plugin version has not been downloaded, Gradle downloads it the next time you build your project or click **Tools > Android > Sync Project** with Gradle Files from the Android Studio menu bar.

**Update Gradle**

When you update Android Studio, you may receive a prompt to also update Gradle to the latest available version. You can choose to accept the update or manually specify a version based on your project's build requirements.

The following table lists which version of Gradle is required for each version of the Android plugin for Gradle. For the best performance, you should use the latest possible version of both Gradle and the Android plugin.

```
Plugin version      Required Gradle version
1.0.0 - 1.1.3       2.2.1 - 2.3
1.2.0 - 1.3.1       2.2.1 - 2.9
1.5.0               2.2.1 - 2.13
2.0.0 - 2.1.2       2.10 - 2.13
2.1.3 - 2.2.3       2.14.1+
2.3.0+              3.3+
```

For More information [Click here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html)

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me a URL which can list all available gradle versions?

Comment: You can see all  version of gradle here  https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle

Comment: Thanks! You can see the image https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ppq41z4000fj97/My.PNG?dl=0 , the latest version is only only 2.5.0-alpha-preview-02, where can I find 3.3+ at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

This error is for **Android Plugin Version for gradle**, not **Gradle Version**!

### Gradle Version

You can find all gradle release versions at its [github release page](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/releases)( Read **Upgrade Instructions** section)

You should set **gradle version** in *`gradle-wrapper.properties`* file:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-all.zip
```

Or from Android Studio: **file>Project Structure>Project>gradle version**

### [image]

### Android plugin version

But Android plugin version for gradle depends on Android Studio & Gradle version and **Android Studio prompt you to update it** ( if you open an old project or if you update your android studio)

[image]

You can find its version at [Android Plugin for Gradle Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html)

> You can specify the Android plugin for Gradle version in either the
>   File > Project Structure > Project menu in Android Studio, or the
>   top-level build.gradle file. The following example sets the Android plugin for Gradle to version 2.3.3 from the build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
 ...
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
   }
}
```

---

### Plugin version & Required Gradle version

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also you can see latest Gradle version in https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes.html.